# Does object literal return a newly created object?

Tags: javascript

I was learning about object literal syntax `{}`. I learnt that an object can either be created like

```
var person = {}; 
person.name = "myName"
```

or like

```
var person = {firstname: "myName"}
```

Now i wanted to pass this object into a function, and so i learnt that objects can also be created on the fly like

```
sayHelloTo({firstname: "myName"})
```

Finally, I typed `{}` in console, and it showed - `Object().

Does this mean than `{}` is actually a function or something that is actually returning a newly created object, which then gets stored in the variable? Is it a function or something else? Is it same as `var person = new Object()` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score -1):

The object literal syntax *does* create a new object but it is not a function. If anything, it's more akin to an operator.

While the spec does have a whole [category of literals (11.8)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar-literals), the object literal is not part of that section. Instead, it's defined later under [12.2.6 (object initializer)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer). As the leading note states:

> An object initializer is an expression describing the initialization of an Object, written in a form *resembling a literal*.

(emphasis mine)